# How to populate GridView with text and images received with Http Calls from REST API?

Tags: android, gridview

[image]

Assume I want to create GridView in android, so that each element of the Grid is image with some textfield (TextView).
I know, there is a plenty of examples on web, but nonetheless, no one works completely fine and efficiently.

please, is there anyone can reference/redirect me to the full explanation source, how to create such GridView? I want each image for element and each Text value to be downloaded by Http Request from RESTFul API.

Comment: and yes. preferably download and rendering process must be done Asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have a grid adapter :

```
public class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private final String[] names;
private final Bitmap[] bitmaps;
private final String[] ids;
public MyGridAdapter(Context c,String[] names,Bitmap[] bitmaps,String[] Ids ) {
    mContext = c;
    this.bitmaps = bitmaps;
    this.names = names;
    this.ids = Ids;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return name.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View grid;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }
    TextView textView_id = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_id);
    TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
    textView_id.setText(ids[position]);
    textView.setText(names[position]);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps[position]);
    return grid;
   }
}
```

after that you should create grid item template in xml like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="5dp"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:background="@drawable/main_item_background_colors">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp">
</ImageView>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/grid_id"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#2980b9"
        android:textSize="15sp">
</TextView>
```

And finally in your activity

```
            GridView grid;
            ArrayList<Bitmap> mBitArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
            ArrayList<String> typeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            final ArrayList<String> Ids = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                // Fill mBitArray from HTTP 
                // Fill TypeNames from HTTP
                // Fill Ids from Http
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                String[] TypeNames = new String[typeNames.size()];
                TypeNames = typeNames.toArray(TypeNames);
                String[] TypeNames_fa = new String[typeNames_fa.size()];
                TypeNames_fa = typeNames_fa.toArray(TypeNames_fa);
                String[] TypeIds = new String[Ids.size()];
                TypeIds = Ids.toArray(TypeIds);
                Bitmap[] images = new Bitmap[mBitArray.size()];
                images = mBitArray.toArray(images);
                MyGridAdapter gridAdapter = new MyGridAdapter(getActivity(), TypeNames, images, TypeIds);
                grid = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.MyGrid);
                grid.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
                grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        // Go To Selected Activity's By click on item grid
                        // Do Some startactivity here

                    }
                });
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                Log.d("NullPointerEx ", "" + ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Comment: is the name of constructor CountryGridAdapter?
and also, please write the code instead of comments //FillTypeNames from HTTP and e.t.c